# model.py(database) structure for college timetable

Tags: python, django-models

I have tried by doing in models.py but still, I have a doubt how to store values(with what model relations) my models.py code is below

```
TIME_SLOT = (
    ('08:30 - 09:30', '08:30 - 09:30'),
    ('09:30 - 10:30', '09:30 - 10:30'),)

DAYS_OF_WEEK = (
    ('Monday', 'Monday'),
    ('Tuesday', 'Tuesday'),)
SUBJECT = (
    ('SUB1', 'SUB1'),
    ('SUB2', 'SUB2'),)
class TimeTable(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(RegistrationModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timeslot = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=TIME_SLOT, default='08:30 - 09:30')
    day = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=DAYS_OF_WEEK, default='Monday')
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=SUBJECT, default='SUB1')
```

Comment: the default values (default='Male') do not seem right

Comment: sorry for the mistake in code, I have edited the code can you please explain some strategy how to overcome @Christiaan Herrewijn

Comment: There is still a  `default='Male'` that probably should not be there. Can you be more specific about the problem you run into?

Comment: I have corrected the code, I am unable to find any strategy on how to relate day, time , subject,(how to write models.py code) Just I need to develop a timetable app that user can edit and save timetable any time. please explain how to overcome this. thanks in advance@ChristiaanHerrewijn

Comment: You need to do the steps from the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/). Once you have that working, you can try to make it work with your model. If you run into more problems, you can edit your first post and add the [mre] and any error messages that you can't solve. Good luck!